# Event handlers return true Javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, return

First of all Hello to everyone, and sorry for my English.
Of course i did not understand completely the use of return within event handlers.
 
and i would like receive if possible some clarification in this regard.
In this document i have som nested elements [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/M99Xs/).
 
Each element has an event handler that colors the same element of red in bubbling phase.
My question is: why with jQuery i can stop event propagation with return false and whit javascript i can't do the same thing?
Any suggestions will be read with pleasure, thank you all.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.x{border-radius:250px;position: absolute;background-color:#CCC;border:1px solid #666;top: 24px; left: 24px;}
#el1{height: 200px;width: 200px;}
#el2{height: 150px;width: 150px;}
#el3{height: 100px;width: 100px;}
#el4{height: 50px;width: 50px;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // first snippet i can't use return false
    function init(){
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('x')
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
          elements[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            this.style.backgroundColor='red'
            alert("clik")
             /*return false*/
          },false)
           /* return false*/
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init,false);
    // second snippet i can use return false
    /*$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.x').click(function(){
            $(this).css({'background-color':'red'})
            alert("clik")
            return false
        })
    })*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="el1" class="x">
  <div id="el2" class="x">
    <div id="el3" class="x">
      <div id="el4" class="x"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @A. Wolff:thanks for the answer, probably i was not clear. I know i can use stop propagation but want understand why I can't use return true in javascript, thanks.

Comment: Ya, sorry, misread your question. That's because `return false;` is a jQuery 'thing', not javascript one. Jquery handle it like this: `if ( ret !== undefined ) { if ( (event.result = ret) === false ) {
event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();}}` So if you return false from handler, jQuery handles it as `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: returning false in jQuery is not the same as returning false in plain javascript. jQuery catches the return value, and if it's false it executes both preventDefault and stopPropagation before returning the boolean. In plain javascript you're simply returning the boolean false, which means nothing, there's no built in construct that calls preventDefault and stopPropagation.

Comment: @adeneo:I understand your answer, and thank you, but why if i put return false in javascript(second commented return in snippet) the outer div is colored and not the central?thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href = "http://stackoverflow.com/" id = "a">http://stackoverflow.com/</a>

$("#a").click(function(){
    return false;
});

document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(){
    return false;
}

document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //the same function to "return false" in the above two method.
},false);
```